# Preventing pinch zoom and double tap zoom on UIWebview

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios6, uiwebview

I know this question has been asked in various ways before, but I want to put out there the issue I am trying to solve. I am loading Google maps on a  UIWebview instead of using the Mapkit. There is a restraint on zooming the map .Therefore , I want to restrict the user from using the double-tapping or pinching to zoom which happens to be the default behaviour of the UIWebview. I am providing separate zoom-in/out buttons for the app user's use.Can anyone provide a solution for the same. Using iOS6 SDK.

```
webView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
```

or

```
webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;
```

The above hasn't worked for me.

Comment: Sorry @H2CO3..Actually, i am in hurry so i am not reading last line...

Comment: @Kamath5687 No, it was Vishal's (now deleted) comment that was worth facepalming - he suggested writing `webView.scalesPageToFit = NO;`, which you explicitly mention in the question as "not working".

Comment: initially the pinching for webview in disabled until u give the above line of code

Comment: webView.scalesPageToFit = NO; this line??

Comment: I think in iOS6 the behaviour might be different. This was happening by default

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to inject html in order for this to work I think.

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=1000px;  user-scalable=0;" />
```